# Attempting to produce a color scheme

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I want to write color generator same as matplotlib

I wrote following code to parse color map and get a result, list of RGB color values

Which algorithm is used to generate the colors in the code of matplotlib?

```
[[31, 119, 180], [44, 160, 44], [140, 86, 75], [23, 190, 207], [148, 103, 189], [31, 119, 180], [127, 127, 127], [140, 86, 75], [148, 103, 189], [148, 103, 189], [140, 86, 75], [127, 127, 127], [31, 119, 180], [148, 103, 189], [23, 190, 207], [140, 86, 75], [44, 160, 44], [31, 119, 180], [23, 190, 207], [23, 190, 207], [31, 119, 180], [44, 160, 44], [140, 86, 75], [23, 190, 207], [148, 103, 189], [31, 119, 180], [127, 127, 127], [140, 86, 75], [148, 103, 189], [148, 103, 189], [140, 86, 75], [127, 127, 127], [31, 119, 180], [148, 103, 189], [23, 190, 207], [140, 86, 75], [44, 160, 44], [31, 119, 180], [23, 190, 207], [23, 190, 207], [31, 119, 180], [44, 160, 44], [140, 86, 75], [23, 190, 207], [148, 103, 189], [31, 119, 180], [127, 127, 127], [140, 86, 75], [148, 103, 189], [148, 103, 189], [140, 86, 75], [127, 127, 127], [31, 119, 180], [148, 103, 189], [23, 190, 207], [140, 86, 75], [44, 160, 44], [31, 119, 180], [23, 190, 207], [23, 190, 207], [31, 119, 180], [44, 160, 44], [140, 86, 75], [23, 190, 207], [148, 103, 189], [31, 119, 180], [127, 127, 127], [140, 86, 75], [148, 103, 189], [148, 103, 189], [140, 86, 75], [127, 127, 127], [31, 119, 180], [148, 103, 189], [23, 190, 207], [140, 86, 75]]
```

what algo do they use to generate those colors?

```
rez = []

for i in range (1, 100):

  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


  # Set x-axis and y-axis limits
  plt.xlim(0.9, 1.1)
  plt.ylim(0.9, 1.1)

  # Disable the axis
  plt.axis('off')

  # Remove the border
  plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
  plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
  plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
  plt.gca().spines['left'].set_visible(False)

  for _ in range(i):
    plt.scatter(1, 1, s=500000)

  import numpy as np
  figure = plt.gcf()
  figure.canvas.draw()
  data = np.frombuffer(figure.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8)
  data = data.reshape(figure.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))

  height, width, _ = data.shape

  # Get the middle pixel coordinates
  middle_row = height // 2
  middle_col = width // 2

  # Get the value of the middle pixel
  middle_pixel_value = data[middle_row, middle_col]

  aa = list(middle_pixel_value)
  rez.append(aa)
  print(aa)

print(aa)
```